# Google Maps Android Api v2 distanceBetween method innacurate

Tags: java, android

to the point.
I am using Google Maps Android Api v2 distanceBetween method to grab distance between user location and some point on the map as you can see here:

```
float[] distance = new float[1];
Location currentLocation = PECApplication.getInstance().getLocationClient().getLastLocation();
Location.distanceBetween(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude(), marker.getPosition().latitude, marker.getPosition().longitude, distance);
TextView distanceView = (TextView) infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.eventDistanceValue);
distanceView.setText(formatDistance(distance[0]));
```

The problem is that the result don't match the result I receive from google maps website. In one of the cases the distance of Google Maps Website was 31km and the result from distanceBetween method was 23,328 KM. 
Someone have a clue? Thanks alot.

Comment: You might consider posting the actual latitude and longitude values that gave you these results. Also, `Location` has nothing to do with Maps V2.

Comment: Just an educated guess: Google Maps will give you the length of travel over roads, footpaths etc, whereas the `distanceBetween()` method just calculates the distance between two points 'as the crow flies' (or more technically correct: the 'displacement'). See also: [distanceBetween() returns inaccurate result?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618016/distancebetween-returns-inaccurate-result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MH is right. If you wanna get the travel distance along a road you have to use the web-service [Google Directions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/?hl=en). Therefor you have to do a http request with a start and an end point of your choice. The response is a JSON with detailed information about the route between your points, like the actual distance, turn by turn instructions and many more.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495030/google-map-api-v2-get-driving-directions) question for some details about the code.