# How to add distance in this For loop in Java/Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-location

As from this page, [distanceBetween() returns inaccurate result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618016/distancebetween-returns-inaccurate-result)
I'm trying to calculate the distance from a user location everytime the user ismoving. How to make this `for` loop, if there is new results, add it to old result, then `setText()` it.
I'm trying with `++` like this:
`tvJarak.setText(results[0]++ + "");`  but did not work.

```
for (int z = 0; z < listPoints.size(); z++) {
    float[] results = new float[1];
    Location.distanceBetween(latStart, longStart, latB, longB, results);
    tvJarak.setText(results[0] + "");
}
```

i edit :

```
float[] results = new float[1000];
        for (int z = 0; z < listPoints.size(); z++) {
            Location.distanceBetween(latStart, longStart, latB, longB, results);
            results[0]+=results[1];
        }
        tvJarak.setText(results[0] + "");
```

it gives weird number randomly. it should be ++

Comment: calculate distance into a variable, and set text only after the cycle. You are missing Java basics. Please pass through some basic Java training before you continue.

Comment: could you provide me some proper link please...

Comment: just any Java basic tutorial will do

Comment: i edit my question, i try all method i can do, still i can not find way.

Comment: you are still missing Java basics, as I said. You will have 1000 more such questions untill you know the basics

Comment: i find no in Google for sum of arrays of floating point numbers.. that the array float come from results LatLng distance,,  and this https://pastebin.com/tzDqCfLS code works but not incrementing as i wanted. i already learn as you say,.if you know what my problem is, please just say with one clue.i'll be happy gladly to seek out more from it.

Comment: `not incrementing as i wanted` so how you wanted then?

Answer (score 3):

Your Problem is, that `results[0]++` adds one after `setText()` was executed.

Use `++result[0]` instead. It will first add one and then execute `setText()`.